# Comparing two mach-o files

Tags: hex, mach-o, diffmerge

I have two mach-o files and i need to find the difference(hexadecimal differed values) in them. is there any tool available for doing this.

i tried using "DiffMerge" but it doesn't have the supported encoding format it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
hexdump binary1 > dump1.txt
hexdump binary2 > dump2.txt
diff dump1.txt dump2.txt
```

This will give you a diff file and you can use the offset in the first column in hexfiend or whatever your choice of editor is to investigate further.

```
2c2
< 0000010 21 00 00 00 bc 0f 00 00 85 00 20 00 01 00 00 00
---
> 0000010 20 00 00 00 84 0f 00 00 85 00 20 00 01 00 00 00
248,254c248,250
< 0000f80 0c 00 00 00 38 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
< 0000f90 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 40 65 78 65 63 75 74 61
< 0000fa0 62 6c 65 5f 70 61 74 68 2f 69 6e 6a 65 63 74 2e
< 0000fb0 64 79 6c 69 62 00 00 00 26 00 00 00 10 00 00 00
< 0000fc0 58 76 18 00 a4 23 00 00 1d 00 00 00 10 00 00 00
< 0000fd0 e0 09 19 00 60 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
< 0000fe0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
---
> 0000f80 26 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 58 76 18 00 a4 23 00 00
> 0000f90 1d 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 e0 09 19 00 60 37 00 00
> 0000fa0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```